# If some matter slows light going through it, is actual causality also slowed?

Tags: speed-of-light, causality

**tldr;** If some forms of matter change the that light travels through that it (like refraction in water or glass), does that mean the speed of causality is going slower through that matter?

I've heard that light travels at the speed of causality.

**1)** I believe that in a vacuum, if an even occurs at a space some distance away and it takes light some time to travel to you from that point, there's no way for that event to influence you before that time.

**2)** Certain forms of matter change the that light travels through it.

**Question)** If you were not in a vacuum and the time it took light to travel to you had to arrive at a later time (through that non-vacuum material), would that mean that minimum time of influence also changes? Or is my understanding of **1)** incorrect?

Comment: If this is a stupid question, please just comment NO and I'll delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no stupid questions. The answer is "no" because the maximum speed is still c in vacuum. The fact that light of for example optical frequency travels at speed less than c because of material interaction does not alter that.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "no", because charged and neutral particles may travel in such a medium faster, read about Cherenkov's radiation. For the light, the speed less than $c$ is a result of causal interactions of the incident light and the medium. For example a wave front (where $\vec{E}=0$) travels at $c$ and only afterwards the resulting wave ("tail") "slows down". It is because the medium is in fact an ensemble of charges, so the "source" of radiation becomes "complicated" (non trivial).